# Simple program in c guessing word

Tags: c

i am writing a word guess program in c, and i am having a problem in my code below while running it.
the code works for some cases but for other cases it doesn't. If the two words differ, it responds with a message containing a "/" for the characters
correct in correct position, a “+” for correct characters in position
errata, and a '*' for incorrect characters as they are not present in the word

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SIZE 40

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {  
    
     int i,j,flag=0,k=0, N=5;
    char  par[5],cod[5], sol[5], sol2[5];

        printf("insert the segret word: ");
        scanf("%s[^n]",par);
        getchar();
        /*for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          if(par[i]==cod[i])
             k++;
        }*/

    while(flag==0){
        k=0;
        printf("INSERT WORD: ");
        scanf("%s[^n]",cod);
         getchar();
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
          if(par[i]==cod[i])
             k++;
        }
        //printf("%d",k);
        if(k==4){
         printf("WINNER ....");
        flag=1;
        //printf("%d",flag);
        }

       else{
            for(i=0; i<5; i++){
              for(j=0; j<5; j++){
              /*if(i=0 && j==0 )
                printf("vollllll");*/
                  //sol[0]='/';*/
                if(par[i]==cod[j] && i==j){
                  sol[i]='/';
                  //sol2[i]= '/';
                  if(sol[i]=='*' || sol[i]=='+'){
                        sol[i]=' ';
                        sol[i]='/';
                    }
                }
                else if(par[i]==cod[j] && i!=j){
                    sol[j]== '+';
                    //sol2[j]== '+';
                    if(sol[j]=='*'){
                        sol[j]=' ';
                        sol[j]='+';
                    }
                }
                else if(i==j && par[i]!=cod[j]){
                //sol[j]==' ')
                    sol[i]= '*';
              }
            }
            }
           
            for(i=0;i<5;i++)
            printf("%c",sol[i]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
 return 0;
}

compliation error--> insert the secret word : amore
                     insert word: astio
                     /**** while its should display /***+
```

Comment: You have unused variables and statements without effect (`sol[j]== '+';` does absolutely nothing) but the program still compiles. What is the compilation error you get? Put the full error message in the question.

Comment: First thing, don't use such incredibly tiny buffers. Make them all `char par[100]` etc. Second, `scanf("%s[^n]", par);` should be `scanf(" %99[^\n]", par);` a) detect newline, b) it's not a subset of `%s` format, c) restricts the length, d) filters leading whitespace, then e) you can remove the `getchar();` kludge.

Comment: ... I see you entered a 5-letter word into a buffer that can only hold a 4-character nul-terminated string.

Comment: @TedLyngmo infact there is no error message just that the code does not do what I want. I put the duty instructions above.

Comment: Your question stated  `compliation error` at the end (and it still does). Your code had lines like `sol[j]== '+';` (which does _nothing_) and it still has.